# CUDA thrust vector specialized expansion

Tags: cuda, thrust

I have a specialized requirement to expand a thrust vector. 
suppose I have vector of keys, K, along with vector of values, V, and a vector of expansion factor,E, which corresponds to key vector. 
I want to copy the values that corresponds to a certain key by (expansion factor) times.  I looked at several Thrust::expand examples but it does not seem to work for my particular usage. Allocating space for result array is easy by thrust::reduce_by_key, but I don't know how to actually expand my vector.

For example:

```
key is   [0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,4]
value is [1,2,3,5,6,7,8,4,7]
key 0 has values [1,2,3] 
key 1 has value  [5]
key 2 has values [6,7,8,4]
key 4 has value  [7]
(This is not code but the website won't let me submit unless I indent these statements)
```

expansion factor array:

```
Expansion factor: [2,3,1,1,3]
desired result array: [1,2,3,1,2,3,5,5,5,6,7,8,4,7,7,7]
1,2,3   are the values of key[0], expanded 2 times according to E[0]
5       is the value of key[1], expanded 3 times according to E[1]
6,7,8,4 are the values of key[2], expanded 1 times according to E[2]
[none]  is the value of key[3], expanded 1 times according to E[3]
7       is the value of key[4], expanded 3 times according to E[4]
```

Is there an efficient way to do this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I feel like thrust::make_transform_iterator will work but I don't know how

Comment: I found an ugly solution:  (1) get three aux arrays that are: begin location of each key, number of elements for each key, and exclusive result for number of elements(after expanding) for each key. (2) make a copy of the exclusive scan result array, and expand it using thrust::expand.(3) use a counting iterator through the expanded array, begin location of each key[(iterator - exclusive scan result)%number of elements] is the result for the current iterator.

Comment: It would be good if you add the contents of your comment as an answer. You will be able to accept it later on and then the question will get off the unanswered question list. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The original poster reported a solution to this problem as follows:

1. Get three aux arrays that are: begin location of each key, number of elements for each key, and exclusive result for number of elements(after expanding) for each key.
2. Make a copy of the exclusive scan result array, and expand it using `thrust::expand`.
3. Use a counting iterator through the expanded array, the starting location of each `key[(iterator - exclusive scan result)%number of elements]` is the result for the current iterator

*This community wiki entry was added from comments to get the question off the unanswered list.*

Comment: thrust::expand doesn't seem to exist in the library?

Comment: oh its in the examples, but not part of the library functionality as such